# Get data entry count using firebase analytics

Tags: android, google-analytics, firebase-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

I am new to Firebase Analytics and I went through some online tutorials to learn about it. I have a simple 'Notes' app (Android) in market, which allow users to create and save notes offline on their device.

It would be great, if I could get a total number of notes that have been created till date with my app. I know, I can add an event which will notify Firebase when user creates a new note, but what about the existing notes that are present in the database?

Is there any way to get such statistics through Firebase Analytics?

**UPDATE:**

I have included a user property as `notes_count`, but I am not able to find a way to see the total. How to do it?

Comment: It is sad to see the bounty expire. Where is the Firebase Community?!?

Answer (score 1):

You could [set a user property](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics#setUserProperty(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) with the number of notes the user has created instead of or in addition to logging the event.  You are [limited to 25 different user properties](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317519?hl=en) total though, so use them with care.

Comment: Can you guide me how to do it in the console? I have added a user property for the count.

Comment: Did you have any luck following the directions in the bottom part of [this page](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/firebase/android/properties) to see your user property?